# How to parse certain string to datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I receive data containing a string of a datetime in the following format:

> Tue Nov 08 11:20:00 GMT 2016
>   Fri Nov 11 08:05:00 GMT 2016

I'm finding it very difficult to parse this into a DateTime. How can this be parsed into a date time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
public DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string dateString)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}
```

Comment: the retunr type should be DateTime instead of void

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Nov 08 11:20:00 GMT 2016", 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jnmp3N).